# Tenho perguntas que quando clica-se nela, o evento onclick chama-se uma div que esta em display - none aparecer

Tags: javascript, css

HTML

```
<a href="#" onclick="Resposta()">
  <li>Como comprar passagem?</li>
</a>
<div class="resposta_duvida">Apareça por favor</div>
```

CSS

```
.resposta_duvida{
    display: none;
}
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
<script>
    function Resposta(){
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".resposta_duvida").click(function(){
        }); 
    });
}
</script>`
```

Comment: Você deseja que ao clicar em: `<a href="#" onclick="Resposta()">` apareça `<div class="resposta_duvida">` ?

Comment: Isso mesmo, tem como me ajudar?

Comment: A estrutura HTML é somente aquele item ou existem mais perguntas ?

Comment: sim, muito obrigada funcionou perfeitamente, teria como me explicar por favor

Comment: minha resposta ajudou?

Comment: sim, gostaria que me explicase

Comment: Bruna da para resolver isso só com CSS e usando checkbox para mostrar e esconder a div, nem precisa de JS, se quiser eu faço um modelo de exemplo pra vc é bem simples até

Answer (score 1):

posso ter entendido errado mas acho q e mas ou menos assim
css

```
<style>
    #div_email {
        display: none;
    }
</style>
```

HTML

```
<a id='a' href="#">Como comprar passagem</a>
<div id="div_email">
    Para comprar pasagem você deve ....
</div>
```

javascript

```
<!-- javascript -->
<script type="text/javascript">
    var btn = document.getElementById('a');
    var div = document.getElementById('div_email');
    btn.addEventListener('click', function() {
        if(div.style.display != 'block') {
            div.style.display = 'block';
            return;
        }
        div.style.display = 'none'; 
    });

</script>
```

Comment: obrigada, me ajudou muito

Answer (score 1):

Como você está fazendo o uso da biblioteca *jQuery* não tem a necessidade de criar uma função. Caso seja mais de uma pergunta, recomendo colocar a `div` dentro da tag `a`:

```
<a href="#" class="pergunta">
  <li>Como comprar passagem?</li>
  <div class="resposta">Apareça por favor</div>
</a>
```

Já no código *JavaScript*

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.pergunta').on('click', function() {
    $(this).find(".resposta").toggle();
  });
});
```

Ao clicar em um elemento que tiver o atributo `class` definido como `pergunta` irá exibir ou ocultar a `div` resposta que está dentro do elemento.

#### Exemplo:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.pergunta').click(function() {
    $(this).find(".resposta").toggle();
  });
});
```

```css
.pergunta {
  text-decoration: none;
}
.pergunta li {
  list-style: none;
  margin-bottom: 14px;
}
.resposta {
  display: none;
  margin-bottom: 14px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" class="pergunta">
  <li>Como comprar passagem?</li>
  <div class="resposta">Apareça por favor</div>
</a>
<a href="#" class="pergunta">
  <li>Como comprar passagem?</li>
  <div class="resposta">Apareça por favor</div>
</a>
```

Comment: obrigada, me ajudou muito